# Has anyone suffered any performance issues with CodeSmith or MyGeneration

Tags: stored-procedures, codesmith, mygeneration

I am new to both these pieces of software. A colleague of mine recommended these two to me. Just wanted to know if the stored procedure code they produce have any performance problems? I would like to use the software to produce stored procedures only. Anything on these two I should know about?

Comment: Are you talking 'bout MyGeneration?

Comment: Yes..MyGeneration code generation software.

Comment: I hear people try to put it down, just because it gets around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, any performance issues with the stored procedures (or other code) that I generate using CodeSmith (or MyGeneration) are the result of me designing the stored procedure template poorly, and not the fault of the codegen tool.

**The output of your codegen is only as good as the templates you use to drive it.** If you're having performance issues (or suspect you might be), profile the stuff you've generated. You may find places where you can tweak your templates to improve *all* your stored procedures, or you may have to special-case a specific query, if there's just one that's suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever come across a bug or performance issue while using our Stored Procedure templates, please let us know and we will get them fixed ASAP.

Thanks
-Blake Niemyjski (Author of the [CodeSmith CSLA Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/generate-csla-code-with-templates.aspx))